# Job doing Stop-Job on self

Tags: powershell, jobs

Just looking for verification here. Can a job Stop-Job itself? I have a script that creates a job that suppresses a service for as long as the main script is running (by way of passed $PID) and I am currently using this

```
Start-Job -name:'SuppressAdAppMgrSvc' -argumentList $id -scriptBlock {
    param (
        $id
    )

    do {
        if ((Get-Service AdAppMgrSvc -errorAction:silentlyContinue).Status -eq 'Running') {
            Stop-Service AdAppMgrSvc -force -warningAction:silentlyContinue -errorAction:silentlyContinue
        }

        Start-Sleep -s 5
        $powershellProcess = Get-Process -id:$id -errorAction:silentlyContinue
    } while ($powershellProcess)

    Stop-Job 'SuppressAdAppMgrSvc' -warningAction:silentlyContinue -errorAction:silentlyContinue
    Remove-Job 'SuppressAdAppMgrSvc' -warningAction:silentlyContinue -errorAction:silentlyContinue
```

My thinking is the job will run, and when `$PowershellProcess` is no longer, then the `Stop-Job` would run. But I suspect the `Remove-Job` would not, since this is the very job that just got stopped. In general it probably isn't a problem, as 99% of the time I do a reboot when my script completes, but I am curious if there is a pattern for dealing with this? Or is it something of an edge case?

Answer (score 0):

How do you expect `Remove-Job` to run inside a stopped job? And why would you want to do that from inside the job in the first place?

The job will automatically enter the `Stopped` state when the code in the scriptblock terminates, so all you need to do is to wait for that to happen and then remove the job:

```
Start-Job -Name 'SuppressAdAppMgrSvc' -ArgumentList $id -ScriptBlock {
  ...
} | Wait-Job | Remove-Job
```

Comment: Indeed, I figured Remove-Job would never happen, and therein is the problem. My script runs, starts the job, which continues to suppress the service for as long as the script is running, and cleans up if my script finishes correctly. However, if the script where to be terminated early, through intervention or crash, my job would stop suppressing the service, which is good, and the job would finish. But it would be left as detritus in the job list, which I don't like. Very rare that comes up, but I figure if there is a way to address it I would. And good point on not needing the Stop either.